# Android SQLite data display to ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have SQLite Database and I want to display the data in the ListView after the user finish the registration form

**NOTE: I'm using Fragment**

**this class is for Registration form**

```
public class DocReg extends Fragment {

    TextView tvDocRegID, tvDocCode, tvLastname, tvFirstname, tvSpecialty, tvCardID, tvRegion, tvLocation, tvContact;
    EditText editDocRegID, editDocCode, editLastname, editFirstname, editCardID, editLocation, editContact;
    Spinner spinSpecialty, spinRegion;
    Button btnReg;
    SQLController dbcon;



    public DocReg() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_reg, container,
                      false);

          // TextView
          tvDocRegID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDocRegID);
          tvDocCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDocCode);
          tvLastname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLastname);
          tvFirstname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstname);
          tvSpecialty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSpecialty);
          tvCardID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCardID);
          tvRegion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegion);
          tvLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
          tvContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);

          // EditText
          editDocRegID = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editDocRegID);
          editDocCode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editDocCode);
          editLastname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLastname);
          editFirstname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFirstname);
          editCardID = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCardID);
          editLocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
          editContact = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editContact);

          // Spinner
          spinSpecialty = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinSpecialty);
          spinRegion = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinRegion);

          btnReg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
          btnReg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String regid = editDocRegID.getText().toString();
                String doc_code = editDocCode.getText().toString();
                String firstname = editFirstname.getText().toString();
                String lastname = editLastname.getText().toString();
                String specialty = spinSpecialty.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String location = editLocation.getText().toString();
                String card_id = editCardID.getText().toString();
                String region = spinRegion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String contact = editContact.getText().toString();
                dbcon.insertData(regid, doc_code, firstname, lastname, specialty, card_id, region, location, contact);


                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                   ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentInsertDoctor());
                    ft.commit();
            }
        });



          return view;
    }   

}
```

**and this is my SQLiteOpenHelper and DB class**

```
public class SqlDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "doc_table";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "doc_db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String COL_ID = "col_id";
    public static final String COL_REG_ID = "reg_id";
    public static final String COL_DOC_CODE = "doc_code";
    public static final String COL_FNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String COL_LNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String COL_SPEC = "specialty";
    public static final String COL_CARD_ID = "card_id";
    public static final String COL_REGION = "region";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION ="location";
    public static final String COL_CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COL_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_REG_ID
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_DOC_CODE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_FNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_SPEC
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CARD_ID
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_REGION
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LOCATION
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"; 

    public SqlDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class SQLController {

    private SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public SQLController(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
        dbhelper = new SqlDbHelper(context);
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public void insertData(String regid, String doc_code, String firstname, String lastname,
            String specialty, String card_id, String region, String location, String contact) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, regid);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE, doc_code);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, firstname);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, lastname);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, specialty);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID, card_id);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, region);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, location);
        cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, contact);
        database.insert(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor readData() {
        String[] allColumns = new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE,
                SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID,
                SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT };
        Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```

**and here I want to display the data using ListView but I only want to show is** `COL_FNAME` `COL_LNAME` `COL_SPEC` `COL_LOC`

```
public class FragmentInsertDoctor extends Fragment {

    TextView tvFirstname, tvLastname;
    EditText editFirstname, editLastname;
    ListView docList;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLController dbcon;
    Cursor cursor;

    private List<Doctor> Doctor = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

    public FragmentInsertDoctor() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.insertdoctor, container,
                      false);


          docList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.LVdoctor);
          dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
          dbcon.open();

          Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
          String[] from = new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION };
          int[] to = new int[] { R.id.docFname, R.id.docLname, R.id.docSpec, R.id.docLoc };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.doc_view, cursor, from, to);

          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          docList.setAdapter(adapter);

          return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_doctor, menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addbutton:
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocReg());
             ft.commit(); 
            return false;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I tried to run this code but I'm getting error from LogCat on line

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.doc_view, cursor, from, to);
```

**LogCat:**

```
05-19 13:45:42.284: E/Trace(4448): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-19 13:45:42.694: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 3% free 6101K/6275K, paused 38ms, total 39ms
05-19 13:45:42.704: I/dalvikvm-heap(4448): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.361MB for 1440016-byte allocation
05-19 13:45:42.824: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 7506K/7687K, paused 19ms+2ms, total 117ms
05-19 13:45:42.934: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 7506K/7687K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
05-19 13:45:42.934: I/dalvikvm-heap(4448): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.969MB for 639616-byte allocation
05-19 13:45:42.984: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 8130K/8327K, paused 16ms+2ms, total 47ms
05-19 13:45:42.984: D/dalvikvm(4448): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
05-19 13:45:43.064: D/libEGL(4448): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-19 13:45:43.114: D/libEGL(4448): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-19 13:45:43.124: D/libEGL(4448): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-19 13:45:43.154: D/OpenGLRenderer(4448): Enabling debug mode 0
05-19 13:45:47.804: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1419K, 19% free 6795K/8327K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
05-19 13:45:47.804: I/dalvikvm-heap(4448): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.325MB for 691216-byte allocation
05-19 13:45:47.844: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 11% free 7468K/8327K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 36ms
05-19 13:45:47.844: D/dalvikvm(4448): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
05-19 13:45:48.874: D/dalvikvm(4448): GC_CONCURRENT freed 724K, 15% free 7129K/8327K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 49ms
05-19 13:45:49.934: I/Choreographer(4448): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-19 13:45:54.444: D/AndroidRuntime(4448): Shutting down VM
05-19 13:45:54.444: W/dalvikvm(4448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd3300)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:122)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:54)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:63)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.droid.FragmentInsertDoctor.onCreateView(FragmentInsertDoctor.java:73)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-19 13:45:54.494: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 13:45:56.434: I/Process(4448): Sending signal. PID: 4448 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class (CursorAdapter and descendants) will not work.

`COL_ID` should be "`_id`" or you can try to use a workaround by making alias:

```
String[] allColumns = new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID, ...
```

See [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Comment: what do you mean by wipe? sorry new to SQLite

Comment: delete doc_db.db from your app's folder throught adb shell

Comment: without it your schema will not change

Comment: so I need to delete that ?

Comment: yes, it's the easiest way to apply your schema change, because it will cause db recreation, or you can modify schema throught sql using "ALTER TABLE", but it's a another story

Comment: but when I opening adb it loads some codes and auto close

Comment: use "adb shell" in console

Comment: delete entire db file

Comment: adb shell rm /data/data/__package__/databases/doc_db.db

Comment: this line is my error now `dbcon.insertData(regid, doc_code, firstname, lastname, specialty, card_id, region, location, contact);`

Comment: open new question for that

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`.

There has to be a column with the name `_id`. So create a column.